# how to use "string" instead of "String" or get it autocorrected in vs code?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, types

I am continually typing `string` instead of `String` in dart. it's very annoying, and it seems some others are bothered by it too: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1410

I'm hoping to have a solution of it being autocorrected in VS code or to have a stable way of simply using "string".

Comment: Not sure where the confusion comes from. The issue you are linking to are about that int and double should instead be Int and Double for consistency and because both types are more like standard object references than basic types in Dart (they can both be null and have methods). See also: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1410#issuecomment-546861455

Comment: For a solution. I will suggest keep writing code so you get it by doing. It should not take that much time to get it into your fingers that it i String instead of string (especially since the analyzer should tell you about the error right away). :)

Comment: haha, yes i do get informed shortly after when typing it in VS code, but i write a lot of c#. c# has the consistency in the primitive datatype casing, unlike dart on this. so, in c#, i always would type "string" instead of String. so, this question was asked hoping for something other than 'get used it'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sygene.auto-correct, but it wasn't working half the time when I would open up VS Code and try it.

For now, I have installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DomiR.regreplace and using:

```
"regreplace.commands": [
  {
    "on-save": false,
    "name": "string to String",
    "match": "\\.dart?$",
    "regexp": "string ",
    "global": true,
    "replace": "String "
  }
]
```

With the autosave feature on for VS Code, this is the closest I could achieve for an automatic solution.

while this is a generic solution above, for this actual data type name, Dart has typedef ability now. Typedefs are alias for functions which are object. So, Typedefs are object with an alias.

here's the documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs

below should work to alias String as string:

```
typedef string = String;
```

Answer (score 0):

Still think that the best solution is "get used to it" but there are at least one plugin for VS Code which can auto-correct you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sygene.auto-correct

I made the following configuration which seems to work (after restarting VS Code):

```
{
    "auto-correct.dictionary": [
        {
          "languages": [
            "dart"
          ],
          "words": {
            "string": "String"
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

The solution is not perfect since the plugin does not understand the context of your code so it will auto-correct every time you write "string" and replace it with "String". So it can be really annoying if you write code like `String string = ""`. You can then manually scroll back and fix the auto-correction. But yeah, that is a little annoying if you often use `string` as a variable name.

Comment: Awesome, I will try it out.

Comment: I will have to look into the possible other extensions. this one worked great after the first restart, except it was doing replacement in json files. so, i was thinking it had identified the whole folder that was opened in vs code as the 'dart' language. 

after closing and opening again, it wasn't working at all. but after closing and reopening again, it is working now again as before. then, i closed and reopened, and now it's not working again. so, i think the extension probably is too buggy at the moment.

Comment: Well, I hope you can find an alternative plugin. I am not using VS Code myself so I don't know which plugins there exists besides what Google can find. :)

Comment: i appreciate your helpfulness. and, here is the issue submitted on that plugin, just in case: https://github.com/genesy/auto-correct/issues/13